# How to allow arithmetic operations when defining dimensional constants?

Tags: haskell

I'm taking my first crack at using [dimensional](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/dimensional); the first two definitions below don't present an issue:

```
aSecond :: Time Integer
aSecond = 1 *~ sec

someSeconds :: Integer -> Time Integer
someSeconds i = i *~ sec

x2Seconds :: Integer -> Time Integer
x2Seconds i = (2*i) *~ (sec)
```

However, `x2Seconds` has a compile error.

Even more surprisingly, this alternative definition has the same issue:

```
x2Seconds :: Integer -> Time Integer
x2Seconds i = let s = 2*i in s *~ sec
```

The error:

```
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘Integer’
                  with actual type ‘Dimensional
                                      (v10 dimensional-1.3:Numeric.Units.Dimensional.Variants.* v20)
                                      (d10 * d20)
                                      a0’
    • In the first argument of ‘(*~)’, namely ‘s’
      In the expression: s *~ sec
      In the expression: let s = 2 * i in s *~ sec
    • Relevant bindings include
        s :: Dimensional
               (v10 dimensional-1.3:Numeric.Units.Dimensional.Variants.* v20)
               (d10 * d20)
               a0
          (bound at src/FDS/Data/Util.hs:40:19)
   |
40 | x2Seconds i = let s = 2*i in s *~ sec
   |                              ^
```

Comment: Likely you used the `*` from `Numeric.Units.Dimension`, not from `Prelude`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, I think I'm hiding that one, here's my custom prelude: https://gist.github.com/bbarker/bb34403c693076c8a9b0625f2cd120a3

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem oh, yeah, right, I had that the other way around - sorry. Indeed I do need the one from Prelude.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your [gist file](https://gist.github.com/bbarker/bb34403c693076c8a9b0625f2cd120a3), the `(*)` function you here use, originates from the [**`Numeric.Units.Dimensional`** module](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/dimensional-1.3/docs/Numeric-Units-Dimensional.html), and thus has type [**`(*) :: (KnownVariant v1, KnownVariant v2, KnownVariant (v1 * v2), Num a) => Dimensional v1 d1 a -> Dimensional v2 d2 a -> Dimensional (v1 * v2) (d1 * d2) a`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/dimensional-1.3/docs/Numeric-Units-Dimensional.html#v:-42-), you likely want to use the [**`(*) :: Num a => a -> a -> a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-42-) from the [**`Prelude`** module](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html).

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds, RankNTypes #-}

import Numeric.Units.Dimensional hiding ((*))
import qualified Numeric.Units.Dimensional.Prelude as NUDP

sec :: Num a => Unit Metric DTime a
sec = NUDP.second

aSecond :: Time Integer
aSecond = 1 *~ sec

someSeconds :: Integer -> Time Integer
someSeconds i = i *~ sec

x2Seconds :: Integer -> Time Integer
x2Seconds i = (2*i) *~ sec
```